# Get attribute id value from a xml in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

please help me to parse the xml with attributes from the given xml..

```
 <tarifs>
<tarif type="internet" name="ОнЛайм 4" price="300" speedin="4" speedout="2"/>
<tarif type="internet" name="ОнЛайм 10" price="400" speedin="10" speedout="5"/>
<tarif type="internet" name="ОнЛайм 20" price="500" speedin="20" speedout="10"/>
</tarifs>
```

I have treid this

```
NodeList node = element.getElementsByTagName("tarif");
for (int j = 0; j < node.getLength(); j++) {                        
    initialValues.put(TRAILER_ID, j);                   
    initialValues.put(TRAILER_TITLE, node.item(j).ATTRIBUTE_NODE.getNamedItem("name").nodeValue);
}
```

But its not working for me.. PLease anyone help me to solve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void vParseXMLList(String sXMLResult)
    {
        org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() 
        {
            boolean bIsMachineNameFound = false;
            boolean bIsMachineSizeFound = false;
            boolean bIsCreateDateFound = false;
            boolean bIsMachineGUIDFound = false;
            boolean bIsTimelinePasswordFound = false;
            boolean bSHAPassword = false;
            boolean bGUIDPassword = false;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
            {
                if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tarif")) {
                    if(attributes.getValue("type") != null){
                        String sType = attributes.getValue("type"); 
                    }

                    if(attributes.getValue("name") != null){
                        String sName = attributes.getValue("name"); 
                    }

                    if(attributes.getValue("price") != null){
                        int nPrice = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("price")); 
                    }

                    if(attributes.getValue("speedout") != null){
                        int nSpeedOut = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("speedout")); 
                    }

                    if(attributes.getValue("speedin") != null){
                        int nSpeedIn = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("speedin")); 
                    }
                }
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {           
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException 
            {
            }
        };
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory;
        SAXParser saxParser;
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
                saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sXMLResult.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                saxParser.parse(inputStream, handler);

        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {} 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {} 
        catch (SAXException e) {} 
        catch (IOException e) {}
        finally
        {
            saxParserFactory = null;
            saxParser = null;
            inputStream = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: remove this line of code, i removed from the answer.
you mark the above answer as correct? right....

Comment: Sorry,

It's don't have error, but showing null pointer exception

Comment: Hi
Now "Attributes" have the error. can you give full sample code please. thanks

Comment: I have try this "getTextValue". but this also showing error. Iam using apk 7 version.

Comment: check the new function that is used before :)

Comment: HI
Now also same error. "Attributes" not declared. can you please explain me. how to create "Attributes"  class

Comment: Hi
After import "import org.xml.sax.Attributes;" attributes, it's working good. thanks

Answer (score 4):

try this way:

```
NodeList node = element.getElementsByTagName("tarif");
int length = node.getLength();
for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
{
     Element terrif = (Element) node.item(j);

     String name = terrif.getAttribute("name");
     initialValues.put(TRAILER_TITLE,name);

     // and so on for other attributes...
}
```

Comment: Hi
The below line showing null pointer exception..

element.getAttribute("name");
thanks

Comment: <tarifs>
<tarif type="internet" name="ОнЛайм 4" price="300" speedin="4" speedout="2"/>
<tarif type="internet" name="ОнЛайм 10" price="400" speedin="10" speedout="5"/>
<tarif type="internet" name="ОнЛайм 20" price="500" speedin="20" speedout="10"/>
</tarifs>